# In c, are variables always pushed from their registers to the stack before they go out of scope?

Tags: c, assembly, callstack, cpu-registers

After a function A calls a function B, can the code in B trash all the registers (aside from those that hold the stack pointers and B's parameters) without affecting variables local to A? Accordingly, after function B returns to function A, does function A pop all its locals back off the stack (reasoning that the register states might have changed while function B was executed)?

What about global variables? Does function B need to worry at all about any register operations affecting the state of global variables?

(The main reason I ask this, is that I feel like experimenting with injecting machine code at runtime as function B by using `mprotect` to make an array executable, and then casting the array pointer to function pointer and calling it. With the above questions I hope to figure out what the extent of B's playground is.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [**`calling convention`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention), which is architecture, operating system, and compiler dependent.

#### Edit 0:

One more link for you: [**`application binary interface`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). Drill down for your particular hardware/OS/compiler combination. You'll find what registers are used for parameters/return values, which are reserved for specific things, and which are free for any given function to *clobber*.

Comment: ABI has nothing to do with variable scope within a function. The compiler has absolute freedom to generate whatever ASM it deems best as long as the observable behavior matches the behavior of the abstract machine whenever the behavior is defined.

Comment: Yes, true, but the question was about use of registers across function calls.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to the functions how they handle calling other functions. It's normal to store all your local variables on the stack before branching to another function, but if you know for fact that some other function only uses a specific two registers, and you avoid using those two anywhere, then you wouldn't need to store anything (other than the address to branch back to afterwards, of course) on the stack before branching to that function.

It is really just a low level implementation design decision (which is usually decided by a compiler) so you might find that some functions will trust B with what's currently in the registers, while other functions won't.

Comment: @WillBuddha I do not know. My guess is that it is smart enough, but with the right optimization flags, might not be.

Comment: This is generally the case on x86 (no doubt there will be a few exceptions), but not on any ARM or PowerPC platform I've come across.